# Trouble walking parallel lists in Python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to write code that draws each rectangles represented by the length-width pairs in the list **sides** at the x-y co-ordinates contained at the same index in the list **coords**.

Where the variable **coords** contains sub-lists of size 2, with each of these values representing an x and a y co-ordinate.

And the variable sides also contains sub-lists of size 2, with each of these values representing the length then the width of a rectangle.

I already wrote a function called **draw_rectangle** which takes as its parameters two integers representing the length then the width of a rectangle.

Having said that now I'm confused to make a `for` loop.
This is what I came out with and doesn't seem to work

```
for pair in sides:
    penup()
    goto(coords[index])
    pendown()
    draw_ractangle(sides[index][0], sides[index][1])
```

or do I have to go

```
for draw_ractangle()
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: what happens now with the current code you have?

Comment: That won't work because you haven't told Python what `index` is. However, there's a better way: you can loop over `coords` and `sides` in parallel using the built-in`zip` function, which you can read about in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem for `enumerate()` and structure assignment:

```
sides = [(34, 23), (65, 72)]
coords = [(10, 100), (-45, 60)]

# ...

for index, (width, height) in enumerate(sides):
    penup()
    goto(coords[index])
    pendown()
    draw_rectangle(width, height)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to see this handled with a zip:

```
for (location, dimensions) in zip(coords, sides):
  penup()
  goto(location)
  pendown()
  draw_rectangle(*dimensions)
```

In general, python style prefers to avoid looping over indices in favor of looping over contents. The `zip` function is a nice way to achieve this, by creating a list of tuples. 
I am left with a concern about the parallel list pattern, which is in general fragile and prone to breakage, and would prefer to see a data structure representing each object to be drawn, to avoid the danger of location and dimension coming out of sync.